# Does every real vectorspace have a symetric positive definite bilinear form?

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Does every real vectorspace $V$ (possibly not finite dimensional) have a symetric positive definite bilinear form?
That is a map $s:V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that:
$$\forall v, w \in V:s(v,w)=s(w,v)$$
$$\forall u,v,w \in V\space\forall\lambda\in \mathbb{R}:s(\lambda u + v,w)=\lambda\space s(u,w)+s(v,w)$$
$$\forall v \in V:s(v,v)>0 \Leftrightarrow v \neq 0$$

Comment: Do you mean $s:V\times V \to \mathbb R$?

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the axiom of choice to create a Hamel basis $H$ for $V$.  So every vector $v$ can be written as $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i h_i$, where $n \ge 0$, $\alpha_i \in \mathbb R$, and $h_i\in H$.

Then for any $h,k \in H$, set
$$ s(h,k) = \cases{ 1 & if $h = k$ \cr 0 & if $h \ne k$} $$
and extend bilinearly.